# Time changed in mysql when i use JPA save the entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

JPA version :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>  
<version>3.2.1</version>

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

Session session = this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.save(user)
```

the data type is ZonedDateTime

```
@Column(name = "CREATE_TIME")
private ZonedDateTime createTime;
```

When I debugged I found that the time was correct,But when I called save, the time it existed in the database was eight hours less than the time I saw with Debug.I checked the database time repeatedly and confirmed that the database time is consistent with my server time, and the time zone is also consistent (both Shanghai time zone).

This event makes me feel whether JPA will automatically convert the time to UTC time and insert it into the DB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is, but I think you analyzed the situation quite well:

> This event makes me feel whether JPA will automatically convert the time to UTC time and insert it into the DB

I think it is the reasonable thing to do, apart from rejecting `ZonedDateTime` at all. A `ZonedDateTime` is basically a point in time plus the time zone.

> This class stores all date and time fields, to a precision of nanoseconds, and a time-zone, with a zone offset used to handle ambiguous local date-times
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

A database normally can't store time zone information, so in order to at least preserve the point in time information it makes sense to convert it into UTC.

Of course, that leaves the question open, what time zone it will use when loading the data again. I guess it will use your (i.e. your application servers) local time zone, which might or might not be what you want.

If the behaviour works for you, you are lucky.
If it doesn't, use either `LocalDateTime` which doesn't have a time zone but also isn't a point in time. Meaning if a `LocalDateTime` is shared across time zones it kind of looses all meaning. And don't if get me started on daylight savings time.
Alternatively use `Instant` which is actually a point in time, represented using the UTC time zone.
Your time zone information should go into a separate field in the database. Again make sure to properly handle DST.

And if you really want to make everything right and your brain hurt, consider that time zone definitions might change over time.

Comment: thanks for your advice. After that, I tried to get the data from the database into the persistent object, and found that the TimeZone in the object was inconsistent with the time zone of my JVM (server) (the server is Shanghai time zone, and the ZonedDateTime in the object is UTC time), which made me very Strange.